# How to run method from child intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My android application has **two intents**.

- First one: main window,
- second one contains the game view (SurfaceView).

  When user push "return" button, main windows appears before the game view indent suspends (surfaceDestroyed).

However I need to run a method in game view before the main windows appears. I've stuck with this question.

Here code:

**MainWindow class:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.StartBtn) {
        final Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                StartActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

**StartActivity class**

```
public class StartActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

**GameView class**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    @Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(final SurfaceHolder arg0) {
            //Do some operations before destroing
    }    
}
```

Layout activity_start

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".StartActivity" >

<com.somepackage.appname.GameView
  android:id="@+id/game_view"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

So I need to start surfaceDestroyed in GameView before onResume on MainWindow intent

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: I've added code to my first post

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if that is really what yiu are looking for, but i will give it a try:

You need to have an instance inside the other Activity before you can call any method there. You can achieve it by using this:

```
 (OtherActivity) getActivity.myMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity.this instead of getApplicationContext(). That May be the problem. If not please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainAWindow.this,StartActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and where is ur OnResume method?... explain your question properly what u want to achieve exactly..?

Comment: OnResume in this code in MainWindow class is missed. While debugging OnResume in MainWindow starts before surfaceDestroyed runs in GameView class. But I need execute this method before onResume in MainWindow